# How do I translate a CURL request to Python?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to translate the below CURL request to a Python request. The CURL request was provided to me by the company who owns the API.

```
$ export client_id="client-id"
$ read -s client_secret
$ export basic_auth="$(echo -n $client_id:$client_secret | base64)"
$ curl -XPOST https://tokenurl.com -H"Authorization: Basic $basic_auth" -d client_id="$client_id" -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

Here is what I have in Python.

```
client_id = 'XXX'
client_secret_id = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYY'
token_url = 'https://tokenurl.com'

basic_auth = client_id + ':'+ client_secret_id

headers = {'Authorization': f"Basic {basic_auth}"}

data = {'client_id':client_id, 'grant_type':'client_credentials'}

response = requests.post(token_url,headers=headers,json=data)
```

This returns a response error [400]. Would love any help in directing me in my poor translation! Thank you in advance.

Comment: requests has built-in support for HTTP Basic Auth with the `auth=(username,password)` argument.  You shouldn't need to specifically make a header for it.

Comment: Also, the python code is sending the data as json, which is different from the curl.

Comment: @JohnGordon These two fixes worked! If you want to post an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as correct.